# How can I get a tf.contrib.learn wide and deep model saved and served on tensorflow serving?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I want to use the export method of a model of type `tf.contrib.learn.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier` to save a model and then write the tensorflow serving client to request predictions on the model.

Can someone explain:

1. How to create the parameters for `BaseEstimator.export` from the result of the input_fn in the tutorial or any other part of a pre-trained estimator?
2. How to create the `request=predict_pb2.PredictRequest()` to send to a tensorflow server instance?

Answer (score 1):

Here I wrote a simple tutorial [Exporting and Serving a TensorFlow Wide & Deep Model](https://github.com/MtDersvan/tf_playground/blob/master/wide_and_deep_tutorial/wide_and_deep_basic_serving.md).

To export an estimator there are four steps:

1. Define features for export as a list of all features used during estimator initialization.
2. Create a feature config using `create_feature_spec_for_parsing`.
3. Build a `serving_input_fn` suitable for use in serving using `input_fn_utils.build_parsing_serving_input_fn`.
4. Export the model using `export_savedmodel()`.

To run a client script properly you need to do three following steps:

1. Create and place your script somewhere in the /serving/ folder, e.g. /serving/tensorflow_serving/example/
2. Create or modify corresponding BUILD file by adding a `py_binary`.
3. Build and run a model server, e.g. `tensorflow_model_server`.
4. Create, build and run a client that sends a tf.Example to our `tensorflow_model_server` for the inference.

If your model is exported using `Estimator.export_savedmodel()` and you successfully built TensorFlow Serving itself, here is something you can do:

```
from grpc.beta import implementations
from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.apis import prediction_service_pb2

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('server', 'localhost:9000', 'Server host:port.')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('model', 'wide_and_deep', 'Model name.')
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
...
def main(_):

  host, port = FLAGS.server.split(':')
  # Set up a connection to the TF Model Server
  channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
  stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)

  # Create a request that will be sent for an inference
  request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
  request.model_spec.name = FLAGS.model
  request.model_spec.signature_name = 'serving_default'

  # A single tf.Example that will get serialized and turned into a TensorProto
  feature_dict = {'age': _float_feature(value=25),
                  'capital_gain': _float_feature(value=0),
                  'capital_loss': _float_feature(value=0),
                  'education': _bytes_feature(value='11th'.encode()),
                  'education_num': _float_feature(value=7),
                  'gender': _bytes_feature(value='Male'.encode()),
                  'hours_per_week': _float_feature(value=40),
                  'native_country': _bytes_feature(value='United-States'.encode()),
                  'occupation': _bytes_feature(value='Machine-op-inspct'.encode()),
                  'relationship': _bytes_feature(value='Own-child'.encode()),
                  'workclass': _bytes_feature(value='Private'.encode())}
  label = 0

  example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_dict))
  serialized = example.SerializeToString()

  request.inputs['inputs'].CopyFrom(
    tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(serialized, shape=[1]))

  # Create a future result, and set 5 seconds timeout
  result_future = stub.Predict.future(request, 5.0)
  prediction = result_future.result().outputs['scores']

  print('True label: ' + str(label))
  print('Prediction: ' + str(np.argmax(prediction)))
```

For more details look at the tutorial itself.

Hope it helps.

P.S.
There are at least 4 more duplicates for this type of question. If someone with high rep could close or group them, that would be nice)

Answer (score 0):

I follow as you give refrence link as :
https://github.com/MtDersvan/tf_playground/blob/master/wide_and_deep_tutorial/wide_and_deep_basic_serving.md

Where you define signature? 
**serving_default**
I think when you export your model then it required.But not mention in your export code. Please define it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing a quality answer.

Comment: You can find **serving_default** here [signature_constants](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/signature_constants.py). Canned estimators automatically define these.